# Scala Count Variable

Tags: java, scala

I've been looking for a way to use a count to iterate through my List but I haven't found a way, I tried to use `var count = 0` to no avail.

Here is my code, can someone tell me the correct way to iterate through this instead of just hard coding 0. Thanks.

```
if(order != null) {
      for(i <- order.get(0).getItems) {
          i.getProduct.getName
          i.getProduct.getDescription
          "%.2f".format(i.getPrice))
          i.getQuantity()
          "%.2f".format(i.getItemTotal))
      }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to print stuff, but your question mentions counting stuff. What are you trying to count? What's the goal of printing?

Comment: I'm just trying to print some details of the order that are stored in a List and need to iterate through the List to access them. Is there no way of just using a variable?

Comment: simple first pass answer is `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` then do `for (order <- orderList.asScala) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a Java `ArrayList` apparently, do this first:

`import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`

This lets you turn Java collections into Scala collections, which are much easier to work with, using `asScala`.

As I mentioned in my comment, I have no idea what you are trying to sum; it seems like you're printing things. But if you, for example, wanted to count all items in all orders, you could do this:

```
val totalItems = orders.asScala.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.getItems.size)
```

There are several other ways to generate the same total.

Answer (score 2):

You can import **import scala.collection.JavaConverters._**    to convert java collections to scala collections. This will take care of everything and you can use scala functions. So no need to get count and iterate through that.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
@for(order <- orders) {
  <!-- Start of For loop - For each p in products add a row -->
  @for(i <- order.getItems) {
    <tr>
      <td>@i.getProduct.getName</td>
      <td>@i.getProduct.getDescription</td>
      <td>&euro; @("%.2f".format(i.getPrice))</td>
      <td>@i.getQuantity()</td>
      <td>&euro; @("%.2f".format(i.getItemTotal))</td>
    </tr>
  }<!-- End of For loop -->
}
```

updated the answer based on suggestions from Vidya